# Trying to upload large file to Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a large file to Google Drive, specifically a 150MB .mov. I have tried a 50MB .mp4 and it works roughly 25% of the time.

```
function uploadFile(fileInput, infomark, type, index = 0, title = '') {
    var _index = index;
    var file = fileInput.files[_index]
    var fileLength = fileInput.files.length
    document.getElementById('divUploadText').textContent = `Uploading File ${index + 1}/${fileLength}`

    insertFile(file).then(function (uploadedfile) {
        if (title === '' || title === null) {
            title = uploadedfile.title.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '')
        }
        var googleID = uploadedfile.id
    })
}

async function insertFile(fileData) {
    try {
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

        let base64Data = null;
        await readFile(fileData).then(function (e) {
            base64Data = e;
        });

        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        var metadata = {
            'title': fileData.name,
            'mimeType': contentType,
            "parents": [{
                "id": 'root'
            }]
        };

        var multipartRequestBody =
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
            JSON.stringify(metadata) +
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            base64Data +
            close_delim;

        const fulfilledValue = await gapi.client.request({
            'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
            'method': 'POST',
            'params': {
                'uploadType': 'multipart'
            },
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
            },
            'body': multipartRequestBody

        });
        let result = await fulfilledValue.result;

        var requestPermissions = gapi.client.request({
            'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + result.id + '/permissions',
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'body': {
                'role': 'reader',
                'type': 'anyone'
            }
        });

        requestPermissions.execute(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });

        return result;

    } catch (rejectedValue) {
        console.log("Failed to insert file into folder", rejectedValue);
    }
}

async function readFile(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    return await new Promise(resolve => {
        reader.onload = e => {
            resolve(btoa(e.target.result));
        };

    });
}
```

I have tried walking through the code and it all works fine, but letting it go without breakpoints brings up an undefined. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think that in your situation, the resumable upload is required to be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) Unfortunately, in the current stage, the resumable upload cannot be used with google-api-javascript-client. As one of several methods, is [this information](https://github.com/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js) useful for your situation? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This might actually work, thank you for the info!

Comment: Unfortunately, it the library did not work with uploading files greater than 5MB for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation from `Unfortunately, it the library did not work with uploading files greater than 5MB for whatever reason.`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.